# Android push notification from Bluemix

Tags: android, node.js, notifications, ibm-cloud

I’m trying to write Android mobile application that interacts with Bluemix push service.

Using  Bluemix node js backend I  generate my push notification  and broadcast it to all my registered devices.

The push notification works great but when I try to provide Additional Payload, I don’t get it at the mobile side while handling the

push event. The IBMSimplePushNotification object has payload member but it’s empty.

My code looks like

```
broadcastNotification(function(pushMessage){
  // Push Notification content
  var message = {
    alert :”Hello",
    url : "https://www.bluemix.net"
  };

  //Custom payload is passed on the options parameter
  var settings = {
    gcm : {
        //Custom Payload to deliver to Android devices
        payload : { "text" : "Hello to Android devices" }
    }
  }

   push.sendNotificationByPlatform(message, ["G"], settings).then(function(response){
     console.log('The message was sent');
   },function(err){
    console.log('Error:'+err);
   });
```

Any details on how to make it working will be appreciated

Comment: We are aware of this issue and currently working on a fix, apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is due to the "text" property containing quotes. Try removing the quotations around "text" and try again, like so:

```
  //Custom payload is passed on the options parameter
  var settings = {
    gcm : {
        //Custom Payload to deliver to Android devices
        payload : { text : "Hello to Android devices" }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your node but that's not a problem, I have tried almost all possible json formats. Btw, seems like the problem somewhere deeper and is not in my code. The bluemix test push notification also doesn't send payload as expected.